# Quero entender como eu conseguiria dividir um número em uma string. Pq eu não consigo concatenar sem uma string e, não consigo dividir senão for int

Tags: c++, string, concatenação-de-string, divisão

Quero entender como eu conseguiria dividir um número em uma string. Pq eu não consigo concatenar sem uma string e, não consigo dividir senão for int

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main (){

cout<<"Digite valor (minimo 5 digitos):  "<<endl;

string a, b, c, d,e;

cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;

string valorA = a + b;

string valorB = a + b +c;

/**if (valorB / valorA)**/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode usar a função **stoi** para converter a string concatenada para **int** e fazer a divisão.

Exemplo de como usar a função stoi

```
// stoi example
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stoi

int main ()
{
  std::string str_dec = "2001, A Space Odyssey";
  std::string str_hex = "40c3";
  std::string str_bin = "-10010110001";
  std::string str_auto = "0x7f";

  std::string::size_type sz;   // alias of size_t

  int i_dec = std::stoi (str_dec,&sz);
  int i_hex = std::stoi (str_hex,nullptr,16);
  int i_bin = std::stoi (str_bin,nullptr,2);
  int i_auto = std::stoi (str_auto,nullptr,0);

  std::cout << str_dec << ": " << i_dec << " and [" << str_dec.substr(sz) << "]\n";
  std::cout << str_hex << ": " << i_hex << '\n';
  std::cout << str_bin << ": " << i_bin << '\n';
  std::cout << str_auto << ": " << i_auto << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

eu encontrei esse exemplo no site [cpluplus](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/).

PS: O site está em inglês.